# How to create and edit database file .db from mySql?

Tags: mysql, database, qt, sqlite

I just want to know if we can create a `database` .db file from `MySQL`. If so, how to create .db file? I already knew that, .db file can be created from `SQLite` and then this .db file can be edited by `Qt` application.

If we can create .db `database` from `MySQL`, can we load and further edit or add data from `Qt` application?

Comment: Sqlite is a minimalist database, whereas MySql is a database server, so when querying the database, you are querying it through the server. You can not create the .db from Qt because in MySql there is no such concept.

Comment: I don't think Qt is directly related to what you're trying to do here. It sounds like you want to convert the data in a SQLite database into a MySQL database, correct?

Comment: No, when I use `SQLite`, I can create .db `databse` file, and I can add columns in this .db file from `Qt creator`. My question is if we can create this .db file from `MySQL` where columns can be added from `Qt creator` like previous one. I didn't mean to convert data.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL needs dozens of files to represent the database plus a server process to interface with those files. There is no such thing as a "`.db` file" that it can create. The best you can do is a `.sql` dump that's in the MySQL dialect, but this is pretty much useless without a MySQL server to restore it to.

SQLite is designed as a light-weight library that can interface with a single file that is self-contained. It's expressly made for the purpose you're describing.

If you want to convert from SQLite to MySQL that's possible, but it's not always *trivial*.

Comment: So, can I use this `.sql` in `Qt` to add or remove some data?

Comment: It's a backup, not a database. It needs to be restored to be useful. SQLite data files *are* both backups and databases.